# Array count showing wrong

Tags: php, arrays

```
$original = unserialize(base64_decode($rows['original']));

echo "<b>ORIGINAL</b><br />";

if ($original != null) {
    foreach($original as $value) {
        echo $value."<br />";
    }

    print_r($original);
    echo $total_originals = count($rows['original']);
}
```

After I unserialize array from database, I am getting wrong count of elements in the array.

`print_r()` output:

```
Array ( [0] => Aadhar [1] => Pan Card [2] => Address [3] => Light Bill )
```

`count()` output:

```
1
```

Its showing only 1 element in the array, it should be 3!? Whats wrongs in it?

Comment: `$rows['original'] != $original`. Do `count($original)`.

Comment: Yeah, counting `$rows['original']` would look to be counting the string from the database.

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you're serializing a base64 encoded string?

Comment: Thank you for answering. i didnt realize i am not using variable :)

Comment: @walther I tried using only serialize() but my string is getting trimmed while storing in database. So I need to encode it and then store.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$rows['original']
```

is obviously a base64 encoded AND serialized string. If you want to count the elements, you need to do

```
count($original)
```

I'm afraid you can't perform a count operation on the string and expect it to return the number of serialized and encoded elements.

Comment: ohh sorry for being silly. Thank you :) ill mark you answer.